# Preventing users from altering default privileges on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, privileges, postgresql-11

I'm testing database permissions on PostgreSQL and i'm trying to prevent a common user (readuser) from executing an 'ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES' statement. However i cannot find a way to revoke this specific permission, and couldn't find anything about it on documentation.

I started a local PostgreSQL 11.2 instance, removed connect permisssions, created a database **testdb** and revoked table creation on the **public** schema.

```
revoke connect on database postgres from public;

create database testdb with template template0 --lc_collate "pt_BR.utf8" lc_ctype "pt_BR.utf8";

revoke connect on database testdb from public;

\c :database

revoke all on schema public from public;
grant all on schema public to postgres;

create schema private;
```

After that, I created a user with read permissions only:

```
create user readuser
       with nosuperuser
            nocreatedb
            nocreaterole
            noreplication
            login
            encrypted password 'testpassword';

grant connect
   on database testdb
   to readuser;
```

Then create a schema **testschema** and granted read permissions on it's tables:

```
grant usage
   on schema testschema
   to readuser;

grant select
   on all tables
   in schema testschema
   to readuser;
```

Even though i only set read permissions on all schemas and tables, the 'readuser' user can still perform 'alter default privileges' query without a permission error:

```
alter default privileges in schema testschema grant select on tables to readuser;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
```

I would like some help on preventing a user from altering it's default privileges, so that it cannot mess up permissions for tables created in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by revoking the EXECUTE from the role `postgres` that granted the default privilege of execute to `readuser`

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE postgres IN SCHEMA testschema REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS FROM readuser;
```